Modifying normals at bent corners to get a flat surface/sharp corner
I've been given a reduced-poly model of a car for real-time use. However, there are many instances where the geometry turns a sharp corner, and the vertex normals at that corner cause the specular reflections on the surface to appear to bend. I don't really care about the effect on the rounded lip edges (they almost abut other geometry). How can I most easily fix this so that the surfaces of the car appear flat and continuous?

Can I easily rotate the vertex normals at the corners to be perpendicular to the main face?
Some way to double-up the vertices at the corner, with different normals?
Something else?


The faces along the right side of this shape are (mostly) co-planar with the faces in the middle, but adjoin faces that bend at a 90 degree angle. The vertex normals along the corner average the two face angles, and cause reflections to bend increasingly across the face.
I need a solution that will affect exporting the model as glTF, not just rendering/appearance within Blender.

what about the Smooth by Angle modifier? Is it not what you want?

Looks like there's some odd shading applied to the object.
Try right-clicking the object and "Shade Auto Smooth"
